# Regular Expression to remove numbers coming after every character except D in range

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to remove numbers coming after every all type character except D in range, <F=`..`>.

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/AnmQHH/1):

```
(?:^<F=(?=.+>)|\G(?!^)).*[^d]\K[0-9]+
```

1. This able to capture number not coming after d. But, It not capture all that numbers at once. It capture from behind. When we delete last captured number, it match next from left to right.

   <F=1H9D6kl>rt7`8`d7

   <F=1H9D6kl>rt`7`d7

   <F=1H`9`D6kl>rtd7
2. number appear first after = not being captured. <F=`1`H9D6kl>rt78d7

> UPDATE no.2: change `[^d]` to `(?<!d)` solve this issue

3. The matching process should in between = and > ,<F=`..`>. But number entered after the `>` also has been captured.
   <F=1H9D6kl>rt7`8`d7

> UPDATE no.3:    After change (?=.`+`>) to (?=.`*`>) and change location to
> end     (?:^<F=|\G(?!^)).*[^d]\K[0-9]+`(?=.*>)`     solve this issue.
> It only capture number before `>`

Expected output: `<F=HD6kl>rt78d7`

> **For all possible cases:**
> Input    :<F=1H2D63k43l5>rt78d7
> matching :<F=`1`H`2`D6`3`k`43`l`5`>rt78d7
> output   :<F=HD6kl>rt78d7

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: <F=HD6kl>rt78d7

Answer (score 2):

ok, we can split the regex into 2 parts and join them later.

- **Part 1** - `((?<!D)\d+`. We use negative lookbehind to match only those digits which are not preceded by `D`.
- **Part 2** - `(?=.*?>)`. We only match digits which are in between `=` and `>`. Assuming your strings are well templated, it would suffice if we only look for `>` using regex positive lookahead.

Final regex after concatenating them both is `((?<!D)\d+)(?=.*?>)`.

It means match only those digits not preceded by `D` and followed by a `>` in the future.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '<F=1H2D63k43l5>rt78d7';
$str = preg_replace('/((?<!D)\d+)(?=.*?>)/i','', $str);
var_dump($str === '<F=HD6kl>rt78d7');
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/JX0j7)

Answer (score 1):

You could optionally match `D` followed by a digit:

```
(?:^<F=|\G(?!^)(?=[^\n>]*>))(?:D\d)?[^\d>\n]*\K\d+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `^<F=` Assert the start of the string and then match `<F=`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
  - `(?=[^\n>]*>)` positive lookahead, assert optional chars other than `>` (or a newline) and then match `>`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?:D\d)?` Optionally match a `D` char followed by a single digit (or use `\d+` for 1+ digits)
- `[^\d>\n]*` match optional char other than a digit `>` or a newline (if you don't want to match a cross lines)
- `\K` forget what is matched so far
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t6m5iC/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/NMmKs).

```
$re = '/(?:^<F=|\G(?!^)(?=[^\n>]*>))(?:D\d)?[^\d>\n]*\K\d+/mi';
$s = '<F=1H2D63k43l5>rt78d7';

echo preg_replace($re, "", $s);
```

Output

```
<F=HD6kl>rt78d7
```

Answer (score 0):

With the look-aheads, and look-behinds, a simple string function may fill your requirements. POC:

```
<?php
$string = '<F=1H2D63k43l5>rt78d7';
echo "Original: $string\n";
echo "Expected: <F=HD6kl>rt78d7\n";


function formatString($string){
    $end = $extension = strrchr( $string, '>'); // rt78d7

    $chars = str_split($string);
    $count = 0;
    $new_string = ''; 
    foreach ($chars as $key=>$item) {
        $prev = $count-1;
        if( $item == '>' ){
            break;
        }
        if( is_numeric($item) && substr($string, $prev, 1) != 'D' ){
            // do nothing
        } else {
            $new_string .= $item;
        }
        $count++;
    }
    return $new_string.$end;
}

$new = formatString($string);
echo "Actual:   ".$new."\n";

?>
```

Results:

Original: <F=1H2D63k43l5>rt78d7

Expected: <F=HD6kl>rt78d7

Actual:   <F=HD6kl>rt78d7